# Where is the apply option in modifiers for 2.9?

Tags: modifiers

As you can see this is a simple question of how to apply a modifier in blender 2.9.  From the image there is no apply option, so where is it?

[image: no visible modifier apply option?]

Answer (score 1):

Right next to the close button there is a little down arrow. It is a pop-down menu where you can find the apply button. You can also apply with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

[image]